# How do you add multiple eventlisteners of different type in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I have an element in my react app that has mouse events. However, it does not work on mobile because all the mouse event converts to touch events. I would do something like this

```
<div onMouseMove={mousemove} 
     onMouseUp={mouseup} 
     onMouseDown={mousedown}
     onTouchMove={touchmove} 
     onTouchEnd={touchend} 
     onTouchStart={touchstart}>some content</div>
```

The problem here is that I didn't want to write so many JSX attributes. So I thought about this

```
const elementRef = useRef()

useEffect(()=>{
    elementRef.addeventlistener('mousedown', mousedown)
    {/* add the rest of the event listeners */}
})

<div ref={elementRef}></div>
```

But that is still a lot of code, so I though about this instead.

```
const eventhandler = e =>{
    switch(e.type){
        case 'mousedown':
            mousedown();
            break;
        {/*add the rest*/}
}
}
```

Then somehow assign `eventhandler` to my `div`. Is there a way of doing that (not just React but vanilla javascript)?

Comment: no I don't know to do it

Comment: you can dynamically assign the event you want, but still, you write the same amount of code for everything.

Comment: You should consider the most readable and less error prone approach... Which is the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the desired props to the object, and then spread it on the component. Eg.

```
const getMouseEvents = (mousemove, mouseup, mousedown, touchmove) => ({
     onMouseMove: mousemove, 
     onMouseUp: mouseup,
     onMouseDown: mousedown,
     onTouchMove: touchmove
     [...]
});

<div {...getMouseEvents(mousemove, mouseup, mousedown, touchmove)}>
   some content
</div>
```